# How to use nested object/array notation in node-fetch headers?

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-fetch

I am trying to make a **fetch()** api call from typescript application based on below specification:

> - Method: POST
> - Request URL: https://cloud.memsource.com/web/api2/v1/projects/KmtNyVlz1skQd2aMVEipp7/jobs?token=AuthenticationToken
> - (Header) Content-Disposition: filename*=UTF-8''file.txt
> - (Header) Memsource: {"targetLangs":["de","fr"]}
> - (Header) Content-Type: application/octet-stream
> - Response: Job UID (e.g. dOYgeXzAdAbj4xFjuEVZP2)

I am getting following error when trying to use nested object/array value for headers in node-fetch call.

> (property) RequestInit.headers?: HeadersInit Type '{ 'Content-Type':
>   string; 'Content-Disposition': string; 'Memsource': { 'targetLangs':
>   string[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'HeadersInit'.   Type '{
>   'Content-Type': string; 'Content-Disposition': string; 'Memsource': {
>   'targetLangs': string[]; }; }' is missing the following properties
>   from type 'Headers': forEach, append, delete, get, and 7 more.ts(2322)
>   index.d.ts(45, 5): The expected type comes from property 'headers'
>   which is declared here on type 'RequestInit'

Below is the line of the code giving the problem.

```
let project: Promise<Response> = await fetch(apiURL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Disposition': 'd:/_export/en_US.json',
      'Memsource': { 'targetLangs': ['fr_fr', 'es_es'] },
    },
  }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => json)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

What should I do to fix the problem?  Am I not allowed to use this notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I researched this matter really hard and learned hat HTTP request headers (or Headers object in Node-Fetch) supports only simple key/value pairs.   That is why the nested json value was failing in this context.

I tired to make the nested value a simple json string by put quotes around the 
 entire json and escaping all the inner quotes like below and it worked like charm.

```
'Memsource': '{ \'targetLangs\': [\'fr_fr\', \'es_es\'] }'
```

Once I confirmed it working, I changed it to JSON.stringify() statement and it worked good.  Oh, I had to make a small mistake correction in the 'Content-Disposition' value.

```
var customHeader = {'targetLangs': ['fr_fr', 'es_es'],};
let project: Promise<Response> = await fetch(apiURL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Disposition': 'filename=d:/_export/en_US.json',
      'Memsource': JSON.stringify(customHeader),
    },
  }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => json)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I thought I might share  just in case someone else needs this information.